# How to validate unique combinations of two column values in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application where I track rivalries between football clubs. But I just want each rivalry to be registered once in the Database

I've added this to my model:

```
class Rivalship < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :team
belongs_to :rival, :class_name => "Team"

validates_uniqueness_of :team_id, :scope => :rival_id
end
```

and this to my DB:

```
class AddUniqueConstraintsForRivalships < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]

  def change
    add_index :rivalships, [:rival_id, :team_id], unique: true, algorithm: :concurrently
  end
end
```

But this only prevents identical records from being stored in the database.
Ex, in the following scenario, the second record will not be stored as validation will fail.

```
team_id: 10 | rival_id: 20 (saved)

team_id: 10 | rival id: 20 (not saved, identical record)
```

**But how do can I also prevent this from happening? Were the combination of rival_id and team_id already exist in the DB**

```
team_id: 10 | rival_id: 20 (saved)

team_id: 20 | rival id: 10 (identical combination, how do I prevent this from being saved?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ***Custom Validation Method*** :

```
validate :validate_team_rival_uniqueness

def validate_team_rival_uniqueness
  if Rivalship.find_by(team_id: rival.id, rival_id: team.id)
    errors.add(:base, "Inverse combination already exists")
  end
end
```

Reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

You'll still need

```
validates_uniqueness_of :team_id, :scope => :rival_id
```

But you can push this into the ***Custom Validation*** if you want...

Comment: Thank you, that did the job!